# Amadeus Self service api

Tags: api, amadeus

I am getting repeated and limited result for flight and hotels search listing in Amadeus self service api. Also search flights data is repeating more than one time. What is the reason? Am I doing any mistake or self service apis only give limited data?

Comment: show your code if you need help

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share your code so we can understand what you are trying to do?

Note that if you are getting limited results it might be because you are using the API in the test environment. Our test environment is based on a subset of the production data. In case you want to see what our test data includes, please refer to our test [data collection on GitHub](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/data-collection).

If you are done prototyping your application and want to access to live production data, we recommend you follow our "[Moving to production guide](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/developer-guides/blob/master/guides/production.md)", it offers easy to follow instructions on how to move to production. Please keep in mind we also provide with free monthly quotas in the production environment, to allow you to explore the data available